# add a string value before every column in a select * statement

Tags: sql, select, concatenation

I am trying to add 'HP' to the beginning of every result from my `select` statement. 
I am currently using:
`select 'HP'+column1, 'HP+'comumn1`, etc.. from table

This works but I am doing this for multiple tables with differing column names so what I want to do is something like

```
Select 'HP' + SOMEFUNCTION(*) from table

where SOMEFUNCTION
```

means any of the columns in *.
Is this possible? All the columns of the tables are `VARCHAR`
Thanks,

Comment: No this isn't possible. Sounds like something your presentation layer should handle anyway.

Comment: What database is this? If you're using something like Oracle, or SQL Server, I could see a solution involving XML. For academic purposes, an answer could be established, although I clearly agree with @MartinSmith, that it probably shouldn't be done in the database.

Comment: You are doing somthing wrong. Will this value always be `HP`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Did you consider a view for this?